# Using tumblr API, post image is not showing up

Tags: php, api, tumblr

```
<?php
$feedURL = 'http://########.tumblr.com/api/read/';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
// $posts = $xml->xpath("/tumblr/posts/post");
foreach($xml->posts->post as $post){
$post= $xml->posts->post->{'photo-url'};
}   
echo "<pre>";
print_r($post);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

This is the script that I have made. I am able to fetch only the first post, but I want all posts to be displayed and the post image is not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working using

```
foreach($xml->posts->post as $post){
    $img = (string) $post->{'photo-url'};
    echo '<img src="' . $img . '" />';
}
```

But its only showing a couple image not all of them any ideas ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out why they don't all load? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($xml->posts->post as $post){
    $post_urls[] = (string) $post->{'photo-url'};
} 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($post_urls);
echo "</pre>";
```

Update for comment:

```
foreach($xml->posts->post as $post){
   $posts[] = (array)$post->attributes() + (array) $post->children();
} 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($posts);
echo "</pre>";
```

Update 2:

```
foreach($xml->posts->post as $post){
    $img = (string) $post->{'photo-url'};
    echo '<img src="' . $img . '" />';
}
```

Comment: thanx, the updated code is working but still images are shown up, only the image url is shown

Comment: Added an other example, is that what you want?

Comment: Hi, thanx for your help, but i want image not url, image src is needed

Comment: Do you mean show the images in a browser? If so the first example is the image url all that you need to do is put the url inside an image tag. added example.

Comment: @GlassRobot let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1322/discussion-between-user799100-and-glass-robot)